# How to aggregate field if specify field existing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have documents like this

```
    {
        "_index": "message_2017-08",
        "_type": "comment",
        "_id": "c000001",
        "_source": {
          "companies": {
            "58f99f99ba63d10006291b59": {
              "id": "58f99f99ba63d10006291b59",
              "sentiment": "58f8898273fabd33ee09d317"
            }
          },
          "sentiment": "58f8898273fabd33ee09d319",
          "purpose": "58f8898373fabd33ee09d31a"
        }
   },
   {
        "_index": "message_2017-08",
        "_type": "comment",
        "_id": "c000002",
        "_source": {
          "companies": {
            "58f99f99ba63d10006291b59": {
              "id": "58f99f99ba63d10006291b59"
            }
          },
          "sentiment": "58f8898273fabd33ee09d317",
          "purpose": "58f8898373fabd33ee09d31a"
        }
   },
   {
        "_index": "message_2017-08",
        "_type": "comment",
        "_id": "c000003",
        "_source": {
          "sentiment": "58f8898273fabd33ee09d318",
          "purpose": "58f8898373fabd33ee09d31a"
        }
   }
```

I would like to aggregate the documents in case,

- if `_source.companies.{company_id}.sentiment` existing use this field
- if not use `_source.sentiment` instead

I try to aggregate like this but got error about `null_pointer_exception`

```
"aggs": {
  "by_sentiment": {
    "terms": {
      "script": {
        "inline": "if(params['_source']['companies']['58f99f99ba63d10006291b59']['sentiment'].empty == 'true'){return params['_source']['sentiment']} else {return params['_source']['companies']['58f99f99ba63d10006291b59']['sentiment']}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

anyone have any idea? how can I check field existing in script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `params['_source']['companies']['58f99f99ba63d10006291b59']['sentiment']` will be null if one of the elements in the path is missing, so calling isEmpty throws NPE.

Try checking if null before calling isEmpty on each element in the path.

Comment: I try ```if(params['_source']['companies'].isEmpty()){return 'true'} else {return 'false'}``` but still error null pointer exception.

Comment: Ok, I got it. It must be

`if(params._source.companies!=null){params._source.companies['58f99f99ba63d10006291b59']['sentiment']==null?params._source.sentiment:params._source.companies['58f99f99ba63d10006291b59']['sentiment']}`

Comment: Glad you got it. Shame there's no way to sort of coalese in a nicer way